# Trypsin and Cell Surface Receptors

Tags: cell-culture, receptor

Can adding Trypsin to mammalian cells affect the expression of or hydrolyze cell surface receptors?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Trypsin cleaves proteins and can do so quite indiscriminately if left on for very long. Trypsin is primarily used to cleave the proteins that cells use to adhere to each other and the plate in culture. It can cleave other membrane bound proteins as well, including receptors.

https://jbiomedsci.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1423-0127-17-36